# Whether the Direct Update function will work without any security authentication mechanism configured?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight studio 5.0.5
Worklight server 5.0.0

The case is: the Direct Update function doesn't work in iPhone. And there is no any authentication configured in both of client-side and server-side.

My question is whether the authentication mechanism will impact the Direct Update function.
Any why does it only work well in Android?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question. You should bump your question instead of creating a new one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568168/worklight-direct-update-is-not-working-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apps built with WL studio 5.0.5 will work with WL Server 5.0.5 and up only.
2. Direct update will function only if versions of WL studio used to build the app and WL server match (equal).
3. Authentication is not required for direct update. The only thing required is for an app to connect to WL server by either using WL.Client.connect() API or setting connectOnStartup:true.

Comment: Thank you, Anton. I will update the whole environment. Later, update the status here.

Comment: Exactly, this issue is because of the different versions between WL studio and WL server. After testing, I confirm it. Thanks again.